# why netbeans not showing system out put within the code

Tags: java, oop, netbeans

I am creating a booking project in NetBeans, I am first implementing a booking controller that will validate user input using the Java scanner. I would like to test the code and input data in the terminal. When I run the output of the code terminal the terminal just shows " Build successful". And shows none of the systems out print code line. I am not too sure what is wrong with the code please see below

```
package fitnessclassapp;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BookingController {       

   private Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
   Customer customer = new Customer (); 

    // customer enter details and the details are validated   
    private String Customer () { 

        String customerName = ""; 
        int customerAge = -1 ; 
        String  membership  = ""; 
        boolean isName; 

        System.out.println( "Please enter your name " );
        do { 
            // name of condition HasNext will check the user input 
            if ( input.hasNext()) { 
                customerName = input.nextLine();
                isName = true; 

                // add a boolean 
            }else
                System.out.println ( "You have provided incorrect information");

            isName = false; 
            input.next(); 

        }while ( !isName ); 

        System.out.println(customerName); 

        return customerName; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: `private String Customer` is not a constructor, it’s a method and you’re not calling it

Comment: Do you also have a [`main`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) method from which you're calling the `Customer()`method ?

Comment: Are you looking at the correct window? Sometimes netbeans doesn't automatically switch to the window containing the terminal.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```
 package fitnessclassapp;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BookingController { 
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
//  Customer customer = new Customer();

    // customer enter details and the details are validated
    private String Customer() {

        String customerName = "";
        int customerAge = -1;
        String membership = "";
        boolean isName;

        System.out.println("Please enter your name ");
        do {
            // name of condition HasNext will check the user input
            if (input.hasNext()) {
                customerName = input.nextLine();
                isName = true;

                // add a boolean
            } else
                System.out.println("You have provided incorrect information");

            isName = false;
            input.next();

        } while (!isName);

        System.out.println(customerName);

        return customerName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BookingController con = new BookingController();
        con.Customer();
    }

}
```

if any issue inform.